# The setChecked of Radio Button its not working

Tags: android

I tried to setChecked(true)

```
RadioButton rbOk = new RadioButton(this);
rbOk.setLayoutParams(ParamWCWC);
rbOk.setText("OK");
if(situacao.equals("ok")){
    rbOk.setChecked(true);
};
```

It's show ok, but there are 3 RadioButtons, and only one is checked, and after this one is checked, I can do nothing to disable it, even if I checked another in the same RadioGroup and the selection become duplicated.

Comment: You can clean this up a bit like this:

`RadioButton rbOk = new RadioButton(this);
rbOk.setLayoutParams(ParamWCWC);
rbOk.setText("OK");
rbOk.setChecked(situacao.equals("ok"))`

If `situacao.equals("ok")` evaluates to TRUE, then the `rbOk` will be checked.

Comment: But if that isn't working, then you need to fix `situacao.equals("ok")` into something that evaluates to TRUE(1) or FALSE(0). Then the logic of your button will work.

Comment: situacao.equals('ok') is working, the RadioButton start on the screen checked, but when I try to select another it don't changes. It's like if it was from another RadioGroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution at this post:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1772#c13

What I needed to solve it was:

```
RadioGroup rgSituacao = new RadioGroup(this);
...
RadioButton rbOk = new RadioButton(this);
rbOk.setLayoutParams(ParamWCWC);
rbOk.setText("OK");

rgSituacao.addView(rbOk);

rbOk.setChecked(situacao.equals("ok"));
```

use setChecked after bind it to the RadioGroup.

Comment: Tricky android.