# setChecked and setSelected not working android radio button

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the selected value from radio button when my variable idAnswerP is equal to answers.get(i). When i debug on my app, shows the number i receive in idRespuestaC but it doesnt display in radio button. Help?

```
public void addRB(ArrayList<Model> answers) {
    RadioGroup ll = new RadioGroup(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
        Model model = answers.get(i);
        RadioButton radiob = new RadioButton(this);

        if (idAnswerP == model.getId()) {
            radiob.setId(model.getId());
            radiob.setText(model.getQuestion());
            radiob.setTag(model.getAnswer());
            radiob.setChecked(true);
            radiob.setSelected(true);
        } else {
            radiob.setId(model.getId());
            radiob.setText(model.getQuestion());
            radiob.setTag(model.getAnswer());
            radiob.setChecked(false);
        }

        lisRadio.add(radiob);
        ll.addView(radiob);
    }

    ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup)).addView(ll);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been checked your code creating this Activity and I noticed that if i use setId(model.getId) the first radiobutton never is checked, everything works properly.

So I am thinking that maybe you have a duplicated id and that is not working good when you are setting the id in the radiobutton.

I let you the code that I've been testing.

**Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int idAnswerP = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Model> answer = new ArrayList<>();
        answer.add(new Model(1));
        answer.add(new Model(1));
        answer.add(new Model(1));
        answer.add(new Model(1));
        answer.add(new Model(2));
        answer.add(new Model(2));

        addRB(answer);

    }

    public void addRB(ArrayList<Model> answers) {

        RadioGroup ll = new RadioGroup(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        RadioButton radiob;

        for (Model model: answers) {

            radiob = new RadioButton(this);

            if (idAnswerP == model.getId()) {
                radiob.setId(model.getId()); //Comment this line and everything works without problem
                radiob.setText(model.getQuestion());
                radiob.setTag(model.getAnswer());
                radiob.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                radiob.setId(model.getId());
                radiob.setText(model.getQuestion());
                radiob.setTag(model.getAnswer());
                radiob.setChecked(false);
            }

            ll.addView(radiob);
        }

        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup)).addView(ll);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't solve my problem. I tested it and I still dont get the radio button cheked. Also, I need "radiob.setId(model.getId());" line cause I make an insert on my database. But thank you!

Comment: I am sorry Gabriela, but i dont know what is wrong with your code, maybe the xml file is wrong?

Comment: Don't worry.  My radio group in the xml file looks like this: <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true" />

Comment: @gabriela Maybe this solution can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287402/the-setchecked-of-radio-button-its-not-working

Answer (score 0):

If idAnswerP is of type String, then there is no wonder, that this is not working .

If so, just change your if case to the following :

```
if (idAnswerP.equals(model.getId())) {
            radiob.setId(model.getId());
            radiob.setText(model.getQuestion())
            ....
```

Comment: It is not a String, it's an int.

Answer (score 0):

you need set different view Id for radiobutton.